# CORS Error when try to fetch data using api

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

Im trying to fetch data from api but getting CORS error. Any suggestions please

Here is the code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.product_id) {
      axios
        .get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://51fgc922b7.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/productpreview?product_id=${props.product_id}`,
  )      .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.data)
          setModelData(res.data.data[0])
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setIsErrorImage(true)
        })
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting.

Comment: Can you please open the console and print the error related to CORS, and if you can add the HTTP request and the HTTP response Headers that would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding **below meta** tag in you index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*" />
```

Comment: Nice try, but you cannot specify a CORS policy via a `meta` element :) It has to come from response headers.

Comment: @jub0bs yes i agree, but when i had a similar problem in one my project i had used above solution and problem was got solved  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Yes, you can use a `meta` element to specify some policies (like a document's [Referrer Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#integration_with_html)), but not for CORS, which needs to be specified at the response-header level; there's no other way around that.